# how to find the minimum value of each row and column from given table

Tags: javascript

i want to find the minimum value of each row also minimum value of each column

1. add input to each row and column produced after the table generation
2. want to find minimum value of each row and minimum value of each column
3. also minimum value of whole table

i want to input the user values instead of default value cell in fiddle given below

[fiddle][1]

```js
(function (window, document, undefined) {
    "use strict";

    var wrap = document.getElementById("wrap"),
        setColumn = document.getElementById("column"),
        setRow = document.getElementById("row"),
        btnGen = document.getElementById("btnGen"),
        btnCopy = document.getElementById("btnCopy");

    btnGen.addEventListener("click", generateTable);
    btnCopy.addEventListener("click", copyTo);

    function generateTable(e) {
        var newTable = document.createElement("table"),
            tBody = newTable.createTBody(),
            nOfColumns = parseInt(setColumn.value, 10),
            nOfRows = parseInt(setRow.value, 10),
            row;

        newTable.createCaption().appendChild(document.createTextNode("Generated Table"));

        for (var i = 0; i < nOfRows; i++) {
            row = generateRow(nOfColumns);
            tBody.appendChild(row.cloneNode(true));
        }

        (wrap.hasChildNodes() ? wrap.replaceChild : wrap.appendChild).call(wrap, newTable, wrap.children[0]);
    }

    function generateRow(n) {
        var row = document.createElement("tr"),
            text;

        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            text = document.createTextNode(Math.trunc(100 * Math.random()));
            row.insertCell().appendChild(text.cloneNode(true));
        }
        
        return row.cloneNode(true);
    }

    function copyTo(e) {
        prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", wrap.innerHTML);
    }
}(window, window.document));
```

```css
ul {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}
input[type=number] {
    width: 70px;
    float: right;
}
table, td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    caption-side: bottom;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <label for="column">Add a Column</label>
        <input type="number" id="column" validate />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="row">Add a Row</label>
        <input type="number" id="row" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="button" value="Generate" id="btnGen" />
        <input type="button" value="Copy to Clipboard" id="btnCopy" />
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="wrap"></div>
```

please give me suggestion about it

also i want to store the minimum value of each row and column.

Comment: how do you going to input values to cells? anyway, for comparing you have to identify all values, find the minimum value and select it

Comment: if you run the jsfiddle you have to enter the no of rows and column @Antosha Shmonoff

Comment: do you mean numbers of rows and columns or values of cells?

Comment: sir i want to input the values of cells individually i.e. i don't want the random values in cells  @Antosha Shmonoff .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```js
const generate = document.getElementById('generate');
function handleTable(cont) {
  const table = cont.getElementsByTagName('table')[0],
    cells = table.getElementsByClassName('cell'),
    all_cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td'),
    size = cells.length;
  let currentValue, minimum;
  const p = document.createElement('p'),
    text = document.createTextNode('Minimum is: '),
    minValue = document.createElement('span');
  p.appendChild(text);
  p.appendChild(minValue);
  cont.appendChild(p);
const rowsNum = table.getElementsByTagName('tr').length,
  colsNum = table.getElementsByTagName('td').length/(rowsNum);
const addInput = function(e){
  currentValue = e.target.innerHTML;
  e.target.innerHTML = '';
  let myInput = document.createElement('input');
  myInput.classList.add('my_input');
  e.target.appendChild(myInput).focus();
}
const getMinimum = function(){
  let cur_rows = [],
    temp2 = rowsNum-1;
  while(temp2--)
    cur_rows.push([]);
  let cur_cols = [],
    temp1 = colsNum-1;
  while(temp1--)
    cur_cols.push([]);
  let values = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++){
    let item = cells[i].innerHTML;
    if(item){
      values.push(item);
      let cur_x = i % (colsNum-1),
        cur_y = (i - cur_x) / (colsNum-1);
      cur_cols[cur_x].push(item);
      cur_rows[cur_y].push(item);
    }
  }
  let cur_min = Math.min.apply(null, values);
  minValue.innerHTML = ((cur_min && (cur_min != Infinity)) || (cur_min == 0)) ? cur_min : '';
  let cur_min_rows = [];
  for (let i = 0; i<cur_rows.length; i++)
    cur_min_rows[i] = Math.min.apply(null, cur_rows[i]);
  let cur_min_cols = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < cur_cols.length; i++)
    cur_min_cols[i] = Math.min.apply(null, cur_cols[i]);
  for (let i = 0; i < all_cells.length; i++)
    if (all_cells[i].classList.contains('result')){
      let cur_x = i % colsNum,
        cur_y = (i - cur_x)/(colsNum);
      all_cells[i].innerHTML = '';
      if ((cur_x == colsNum-1) && (cur_min_rows[cur_y] != Infinity))
        all_cells[i].innerHTML = cur_min_rows[cur_y];
      if ((cur_y == rowsNum-1) && (cur_min_cols[cur_x] != Infinity))
        all_cells[i].innerHTML = cur_min_cols[cur_x];
    }
}
const removeInput = function(e){
  let elem = e.target;
  if (!elem.classList.contains('my_input')) {
    for (let i = size; i--;){
      let input = cells[i].getElementsByClassName('my_input')[0];
      if(input) {
        let value = input.value;
        cells[i].removeChild(input);
        if(value){
          value = value.replace(/ /g,'');
          cells[i].innerHTML = value;
          getMinimum();
        }
        else {
          cells[i].innerHTML = currentValue;
          currentValue = '';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
for (let i = size; i--;)
  cells[i].addEventListener('click', addInput);
document.body.addEventListener('click', removeInput, true);
};
const generateRow = function(cols, isLast){
  let row = document.createElement('tr');
  const className = (isLast) ? 'result' : 'cell';
  for (let i = cols; i--;) {
    let cell = document.createElement('td');
    cell.classList.add(className);
    row.appendChild(cell);
  }
  let cell = document.createElement('td');
  cell.classList.add('result');
  row.appendChild(cell);
  if(isLast)
    cell.classList.remove('result');
  return row;
}
const generateTable = function(e){
  const wrap = document.getElementById('wrap'),
    rows = document.getElementById('rows'),
    columns = document.getElementById('columns'),
    newTable = document.createElement('table');
  let row;
  for (let i = 0; i <= rows.value; i++ ){
    if(i == rows.value)
      row = generateRow(columns.value, true);
    else
      row = generateRow(columns.value, false);
    newTable.appendChild(row);
  }
  if (wrap.hasChildNodes())
    wrap.innerHTML = '';
  wrap.appendChild(newTable);
  handleTable(wrap);
};
generate.addEventListener('click', generateTable);
```

```css
.result, .cell{
  width:30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align:center;
}
.cell {
  border:1px solid;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.my_input {
  width: 25px;
  text-align:center;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
}
ul {
  width: 200px;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
input[type=number] {
  width: 70px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label>Rows</label>
      <input type="number" id="rows" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Columns</label>
      <input type="number" id="columns" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="button" value="Generate" id="generate">
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
<div id="wrap"></div>
```

Comment: i want to add rows and columns from user input.

Comment: run loop and get all nested values, checking the minimum with each iteration

Comment: how to find the minimum value of each row as well as column

Comment: @VikramYadav you have to add condition with index checking

Comment: very helpful but i want to take rows and columns from user input i.e if user put rows :4 columns :6  (i want to generate the table dynamically)

Comment: @VikramYadav ok, this is community for helping people, not for working for people. I've solved most part of your task, so now you can easily add any functionality as you want.

Comment: @ Antosha Shmonoff Sir. yes .if i stuck at something i'll ask for your help.

Comment: @ Antosha Shmonoff I have this dynamically created table and i tried to find the minimum value of row and column of the table. please see http://jsfiddle.net/EKfut/2/ for my table creation . will you please help me.